# c# BeginGetResponse: is there any reason to read bytes asynchronously in response callback?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

The MSDN sample code for BeginGetResponse has two asynchronous calls, one to get the response,
and one to read from the response buffer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx

See this line:

```
// Begin the Reading of the contents of the HTML page and print it to the console.
  IAsyncResult asynchronousInputRead = responseStream.BeginRead(myRequestState.BufferRead, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), myRequestState);
```

My question is: what is the advantage here, vs. a synchronous read?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I've gathered from further investigation: even though the callback is happening on a non-UI thread, the asynchronous read prevents this thread from blocking.
While the thread is blocked, it cannot be re-used by the thread pool, and another concurrent request may cause the pool to create one more thread, which incurs some overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the advantage is that you can still do stuff with your UI Thread after a asynchronous call

Comment: Yes, but in this case, BeginRead is being called from a callback; no UI thread is involved. So why not just do a synchronous read?